# I'm trying to print values from a table using PreparedStatement in Java, but I get column names instead of values

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using below code to print columns from a tables using **PreparedStatement**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/javatesting";

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "password");

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("Select ?,?,? from test where salary> ?");

    preparedStatement.setString(1, "name");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "dept");
    preparedStatement.setString(3, "salary");
    preparedStatement.setInt(4, 25000);

    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    while(resultSet.next()){
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("name")+","+resultSet.getString("dept")+","+
                resultSet.getString("salary"));
    }
```

The output of above code looks like this:

```
name,dept,salary
name,dept,salary
name,dept,salary
```

There are actual(valid) values in the table, still I end up printing the column names instead of values.

The output that I'm expecting to get printed looks something like this:

```
Ben,IT,30000
Marie,BPO,35000
Subash,IT,30000
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the PreparedStatement escapes the values that are passed via a `?`.

So `name` becomes `"name"` and `SELECT "name"` always returns `name`.

You should change your query:

```sql
SELECT name, dept, salary FROM test WHERE salary > ?
```

```java
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 25000);
```

Comment: Excellent observation.